# How do I make use figma UI for a desktop app?

Tags: user-interface, integration, desktop-application, user-experience, figma

I have a few UI designs made in figma which I want to use in a desktop application made using C/C++ or Python. Is it possible to import the the designs into the codebase or is it just a blueprint design I have to recreate from scratch using something like Qt/GTK or any other GUI library

Answer (score 0):

Yes, via the [Figma API](https://www.figma.com/developers/api) and/or [Figma Plugin API](https://www.figma.com/plugin-docs/api/api-reference/).

If you want to see this in action, check out the FigAct plugin, which generates ReactJS code from Figma files.

https://www.figma.com/community/plugin/1079641487885770780/FigAct----Figma-to-React%2C-React-Hooks%2C-React-Router-and-dynamic-data-display-from-API-call